# Find r in terms of theta

Tags: geometry

I have been given the following question:

[image]

My answer for question a) is $\theta/(2\pi)$. The books answer is $(2\pi-theta)/(2\pi)$.

I came to my answer by calculating the arc length of the sector which is theta.
Then I set up an equation making the arc length equal to the circumference of the circle hence $\theta = 2*\pi*r$.

Comment: The circumference of the bottom of the cone is *what's left over* after the little part that subtends an angle $\theta$ is removed.  But there **is** ambiguity. Your interpretation is reasonable, it is just not the intended one.

Comment: Thanks :) That makes sense

Comment: You are welcome. So to be clear, it is the "big" part that is made into a cone. The small part gets shredded.

Comment: Got it. Question a until c is easy, yet I am struggling with question d. I find the derivative of the formula in terms of theta and then set that equation to 0. Easier said then done, finding the derivative is a mission and solving is even a bigger mission, am I overcomplicating it?

Comment: I will write a comment (if short) or an answer in a few hours if the question has not been answered or closed.

Comment: MSE was offline for a while. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 1):

In response to a comment, we show how to solve d), maximizing the volume.

We summarize calculations that you undoubtedly made. The circumference of the base of the cone is $2\pi -\theta$. (This was taken care of in a comment.)

So if the radius of the base is $r$ then $2\pi r=2\pi -\theta$, and therefore $$r=1-\frac{\theta}{2\pi}.$$

By the Pythagorean Theorem, the height $h$ of the cone is given by 
$$h=\sqrt{ 1-\left(1-\frac{\theta}{2\pi }\right)^2}.$$

The volume is $\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2h$. This is what we want to maximize. My typing fingers are tired, just *imagine* writing down an expression for volume in terms of $\theta$. We will use a method which bypasses that.

We want to maximize the volume, **or equivalently** maximize $r^2h$, **or equivalently** maximize $(r^2)^2 h^2$.  Let $w=r^2$. We want to maximize $w^2(1-w)$, that is, $w^2-w^3$, where $0\le w\le 1$.

This is a very easy calculus problem,   We get $w=\frac{2}{3}$.  But $w=\left( 1-\frac{\theta}{2\pi}              \right)^2$ and solving for $\theta$ is straightforward. We get
$$\theta=2\pi\left(1-\sqrt{2/3}\right).$$

**Remark:** The calculation **could** have been made by expressing volume explicitly as a function of $\theta$, and differentiating. However, the expression, though fundamentally simple, is rather daunting. At the very least one should make the substitution $t=1-\frac{\theta}{2\pi}$.

When we are maximizing/minimizing an expression $E$ that involves square roots, we can often simplify calculations by instead maximizing/minimizing $E^2$.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a very nice solution

Comment: You are welcome. The "raw" expression **is** scary, but there is less to it than meets the eye.